# Pyspark streaming output not getting printed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingExercise")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
stream = ssc.queueStream([sc.parallelize([(1,"a"), (2,"b"),(1,"c"),(2,"d"),(1,"e"),(3,"f")],3)],True)
stream1=stream.map(lambda x: x[0])
largest=stream1.transform(lambda rdd: rdd.top(1))
largest.pprint(num=30)
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The above code is running well without any errors but not printing the output.

Comment: It's 2023, you don't need to use Legacy Spark Streaming - use Structured Streaming: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html